# fill_between gives "ValueError: Argument dimensions are incompatible"

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib, xlrd

Code below written in Python imports data from Excel to Python, then plots with matplotlib. I'm trying to fill above and below line 80 with different colors using the `fill_between` function, but it gives

```
ValueError: Argument dimensions are incompatible
```

**Note:** the Excel file (`'eegg.xlsx'`) has 4 columns with 682 rows and contains `int` data (0-100).

I think the problem is with the `where` argument of the `fill_between` calls, but I cannot solve this.

```
import xlrd
import numpy
from datetime import time
from pylab import *

workbook = xlrd.open_workbook('eegg.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.sheet_by_name('Sayfa1')
num_rows = worksheet.nrows - 1
num_cells = worksheet.ncols - 1
curr_row = -1

att=[]
med=[]
for i in [2,3]:
    kolon = worksheet.col(i)
    for x in kolon[1:]:
        d= int(x.value)
        if i==2:
            att.append(d)
        elif i==3:
            med.append(d)

n = len(att)
X = np.linspace(0,n,n,endpoint=True)
Y1 = att
plot(X, Y1, color='blue', alpha=1.00)
fill_between(X, 0, Y1, (Y1) > 80, color='red', alpha=.25)
fill_between(X, 0, Y1, (Y1) < 80, color='blue', alpha=.25)
xlim(0,n), xticks([])
ylim(0,110), yticks([])
```

Comment: can you print out the shapes of `X` and `Y1`? Do `print X.shape, Y1.shape`.

Comment: Although knowing the kind of error being raised might help us to solve the problem, it would be _much_ easier if you post the **complete traceback**, as this tells us _where_ the error is raised.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You get this error because `Y1` is a `list`, not an `numpy.array`, and therefore `(Y1) > 80` and `(Y1) < 80` return a single `bool` each, not an array of them, as the kwarg `where` accepts.

So replacing the line

```
Y1 = att
```

with

```
Y1 = array(att)
```

should solve the problem.

Answer (score 4):

Make sure to convert X and Y1 to pandas.core.series.Series. That should solve the problem. You can check the type with:

```
type(X)
type(Y1)
```

If both return "pandas.core.series.Series" then it should work.

Just for illustration, if X, Y are dataframes, then try the following:

```
X = X.iloc[:,0]  # NEW
Y = Y.iloc[:,0]  # NEW
```

Answer (score 3):

It seems that arguments color and alpha need to be passed as color =...,alpha=...

Correct: ax.fill_between(x, y_min, y_max,color = color, alpha=0.1)

Wrong: ax.fill_between(x, y_min, y_max,color, alpha=0.1)

Comment: Yes, this was my issue. Most other `matplotlib` functions are explicit about this exact mistake, though. This exception is unexpected.